# Document.goToByIdAsync method (JavaScript API for Office) broken in Excel 2016

Tags: javascript, excel

According to this page...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn482498.aspx

...it is possible to select a table or range in an Excel spreadsheet using JavaScript.  Well they were right for 2010 and 2013, but I have just upgraded to 2016 and it no longer works.  I have tried a blank spreadsheet with a very basic table, but nothing works any more.

I'm not a beginner at this, having been on it for the last 8 months, so I am pretty sure I am right, but I'd really love to be proven wrong, because I need this to work.

As tables and ranges are a fundamental part of all of the documentation, this is going to be a big problem.

Any ideas anyone? It feels like a security issue, but I have checked all the Trust Center settings and everything is in order.

Comment: Can't test just now, but one minor point... JavaScript API for Office did not exist until Ofiice 2013.

Comment: Strangely my client said they were on 2010, but now it appears they are on 2013 after all.

That aside, I've worked out what is happening and a solution.
I was using a local reference to the office.js file.

When I switched it to the Microsoft.com hosted office.js everything worked.

So there must be some differences that they are not telling us about.

Comment: you could turn your comment in an actual answer, and eventually mark that as the answer